# Draw Anti-Aliased Text Image like Graphics Software

Tags: c#, wpf, gdi+, gdi, text-rendering

I would like to generate text images like the following (source: http://www.zune.net/en-US):

[image: nice font rendering]

The text has a nice thickness and is perfectly anti-aliased. Vector graphics software – such as Inkscape – produces the same result. However, the images I managed to create using GDI+ look like this:

[image]

These rendered text is too thin although the font family, size, weight etc. are identical. How can I increase the thickness of the text? Does WPF provide functionality to render the text as described above?

---

**[Update]** I created the following images using `TextRenderer.DrawText()`. The first one uses `TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit`, the second one `TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias`:

[image: TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit]

[image: TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias]

Comment: Use TextRenderer.DrawText, not Graphics.DrawString.  Don't use ClearType anti-aliasing for art that goes on a web site.  And hire that team of designers that ensure everything is pixel-perfect.

Comment: I used `TextRenderer.DrawText` (see updated post) to render the text but still the letters are thinner than I want them to. Do you know a way to render the text the "zune way"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to create nice-looking text images by rendering a WPF User Control containing a `TextBlock` inside a `Canvas` to a `RenderTargetBitmap` that – using a `PngBitmapEncoder` – is saved to a `MemoryStream` and turned to an image using `Image.FromStream(Stream)`.